# Page footer with page numbers

Tags: css, dompdf

I just downloaded dompdf 0.83. Generating works fine. What I'd like to have is a footer like: page 1 of 10.
Neither css works, nor script versions. When using script, I got an error, unknown variable "$PAGE_COUNT".

With css I got the actual number (same with script) but not the total amount of pages. I trid tons of eambels, none worked.

```html
<?php  require_once "dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'Courier');
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
  $html='
<html>
<head>
<style>#footer { position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 10px; text-align: center;border-top: 1px solid black;}
        #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, decimal) " osssf "counter(pages, decimal); }
 @page { margin: 20px 30px 40px 50px; }</style>
</head>
  <body>
   <div id="footer">
    <script type="text/php">
    if (isset($pdf))
    {
        $x = 72;
        $y = 18;
        $text = "{PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";
        $font = $fontMetrics->get_font("helvetica", "bold");
        $size = 6;
        $color = array(255,0,0);
        $word_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $char_space = 0.0;  //  default
        $angle = 0.0;   //  default
        $pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);
    }
</script>Peep '.$PAGE_COUNT.'
  </div> </body></html>';
 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper("A4", "portrait");

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf ->stream();
?>
```

The $PAGE_Num works fine. Even by css. What's the matter?
Regards
tsunami

Answer (score 0):

The error "unknown variable $PAGE_COUNT" is due to the `$PAGE_COUNT.` in this line, I suppose:

```
</script>Peep '.$PAGE_COUNT.'
```

In my case `$text = "page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}";` and `$pdf->page_text($x, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color, $word_space, $char_space, $angle);` inside  `if ( isset($pdf) ) { ... }` is sufficient to make the pagination work.

Comment: Tried it. <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: PAGE_COUNT in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\Neu2.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />

Comment: Did you erase that `'.$PAGE_COUNT.'` after `</script>Peep`?

Comment: No. Just peep in the footer. No Page 1 of 1

Comment: well, but then that's the cause for that error. Additionally try different parameters inside the `if (isset($pdf)) { ... }` clause

Comment: I already did. Guessing the position is out of document I used 120 and 123 for y and x. What else could it be?

Comment: Hmm - I am not sure if you really can expect a position inside the footer by putting the script into the footer DIV. With your position settings ($x and $y) *outside* any DIV (right after the opening `body` tag) I get a position at the upper left of the page. Could it be covered by something else there?

Comment: I just noticed: Your `#footer`   has fixed position, but no width or height. That could be a reason. Try to add 100% width and some height.

Comment: Nope. Only the border-top is now upper...
Nothing covers.After the body text, half of the page is free...